# Assign columns to new datasets with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, portfolio, tidyquant

I tried to do a for loop to assign firms to different funds. I've created a dataset of 2000 different companies. Now I would like to assign the first 50 to fund1, the next 50 to fund2 and so on.

```
Fund <- list()
for (i in seq(1, 1950, 50)) {
   
   Fund <- subset(artif_company[, i:(i+50)])
    
}
```

I tried it like that but it doesn't do the right thing xD.
Does anybody know how to do that? Or is there another trick probably using tidyquant?

Comment: what's your expected output? could you also add a reproducible example?

Comment: I try to assign the first 50 "assets" to fund1, the next 50 to fund2 and so on. For each of the funds I get (2000/50 = 40 funds) I would like to calculate the mean return.

Comment: ```set.seed(19914159)
 n <- 3 
 artif_company <- tibble(Company = rnorm(n, mean = 0.07, sd = 0.2))

for (i in 1:1999) {
i <- tibble(Company = rnorm(n, mean = 0.07, sd = 0.2))
artif_company <- cbind2(artif_company, i)
}

Fund <- list()
for (i in seq(1, 1950, 50)) {
       Fund <- subset(artif_company[, i:(i+50)])
}```

Comment: Greetings! It would be more helpful to add your code chunk in the comments into the question itself. Listing it in the comments makes it harder to read/work with.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
companies <- 1:2000
funds <- data.frame(matrix(data = companies, nrow = 50, byrow = F))
names(funds) <- paste0("fund", 1:ncol(funds))
```

Comment: Well I do have the dataset of the artificial companies with the returns. But I don't really know how to assign them columnwise to the funds. I need 40 funds consisting 50 companies each

Comment: why do you want n=3 random draws, i.e. multiple observations per firm? The result would then not fit in a two-dimensional matrix... how should your output look like? 50row,40cols? Then you would need to draw only 1 per company, or multiple and then aggregate to 1

Comment: That should be the random returns of each firm for 3 years.

```funds <- data.frame(matrix(data = artif_company, nrow = 50, byrow = F))
names(funds) <- paste0("fund", 1:ncol(funds))```

When I do that, I get 40 funds with 50 firms each, but the entries are vectors. Not sure if I can access e.g., the first element of each vector(firm) of fund 1.

Comment: My goal is to compute the mean return of each fund in year 1 and year 2.

Exactly, I tried to get 50rows and 40 cols

Well I could also compute two dataframes, one with year 1 return and the other with year 2 returns? In order to not get vectors as entries. Isn't that possible?

Comment: n.years = 2
return <- replicate(2000, mean(rnorm(n.years, mean = 0.07, sd = 0.2)))
funds <- data.frame(matrix(data = return, nrow = 50, byrow = F))
names(funds) <- paste0("fund", 1:ncol(funds))
apply(funds, 2, mean)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).